# How can i remove scroll bar from right side of my react <Scroll/> component by only using pure inline CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

*Scroll.js*

```
const Scroll = (props)=>{
    console.log(props.children);
    return (
        <div style={{overflowY:'scroll',scrollbar:'diplay:none',border:'5px solid black',height:'500px'}}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Scroll;
```

**How can I remove the Scroll bar at the right side of the image below only by using CSS here?**

[image]

Comment: Does `overflowY: hidden` works for you?

Comment: @Imanpal  it's working but now it does not scroll anymore I just want to hide the scroll bar only to keep its scrolling functionality

Answer (score 0):

*Scroll.js*

```
import './Scroll.css';
const Scroll = (props)=>{
    console.log(props.children);
    return (
        <div id='scroll' style={{overflowY:'scroll',border:'5px solid black',height:'500px'}}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Scroll;
```

I create *Scroll.css* and added

```
#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
  }

#scroll {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
```

it works

Comment: I want to define everything as an inline css

Answer (score 0):

if you want to give everything as an inline CSS you can try this

```
import React from 'react';

const Scroll = (props) => {

const scrollStyle = {
  overflowY: 'scroll',
  border: '5px solid black',
  height: '500px',
  msOverflowStyle: 'none', // IE and Edge
  scrollbarWidth: 'none', // Firefox
  WebkitScrollbar: { display: 'none' }, // Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari, and Opera     
  };

 

  return (
    <div id="scroll" style={scrollStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scroll;
```